# How to bounce ball using box2d in cocos2d

Tags: box2d, cocos2d-x, bounce

I want to create bouncy ball like ball jump. example game link is 
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bouncy-ball-free/id581876745?mt=8

I am using box2d to continuously jump but want to move in right and left direction how i handle those thing in box2d and some one kindly share this type of box2d example link to handle ball  in cocos2dx

Answer (score 4):

It is tempting to use setTransform(...) on a b2Body to move the body from left to right.

In the past when I have done this, if it was done every frame (such as moving the body to the left), the collision detection would start to fail and the body would not behave as I wanted.  I was able to "jump" a body occasionally to from one location to another (this is handy for a "portal" effect), but not every frame...it just made things "not work as expected".

I think the best solution is to use the physics engine and apply forces to the body to make it  move the direction you want.  This is a "seek" behavior, moving to the left or right.

Below is the code for the ApplyThrust(...) method of a MovingEntity class.

```
   void ApplyThrust()
   {
      // Get the distance to the target.
      Vec2 toTarget = GetTargetPos() - GetBody()->GetWorldCenter();
      toTarget.Normalize();
      Vec2 desiredVel = GetMaxSpeed()*toTarget;
      Vec2 currentVel = GetBody()->GetLinearVelocity();
      Vec2 thrust = desiredVel - currentVel;
      GetBody()->ApplyForceToCenter(GetMaxLinearAcceleration()*thrust);
   }
```

This class simulates an entity that moves and rotates.  In this case, you only want to "move" left or right by setting the position of the target to the left or right of your ball.

This method applies thrust to make the b2Body move towards a target direction.  It has a maximum speed it can travel (GetMaxSpeed()) and a maximum linear acceleration (GetMaxLinearAcceleration()) as properties of the class.

If you follow the code and draw the vectors, you will see that what this does is apply thrust to drive your velocity so it is pointing at the position of the target.

Another way to look at it:  **It acts like a feedback loop in (in vectors) to keep your velocity matched up with the desired velocity.** If you just think about it in terms of scalars, it is a little easier to see.

If you are moving to the right (currentVel) at 5 m/s and your maximum speed (desiredVel) is 6 m/s, the thrust will be positive to the right, pushing you faster to the right (desiredVel - currentVel = +1).  That is to say, you will speed up to the right.

If you are moving to the right (currentVel) at 7 m/s and your maximum speed (desiredVel) is 6 m/s, the thrust will be negative, point to the left, slowing you down (desiredVel - currentVel = -1).

From update to update of the physics, this makes your body move in the direction of the target at the speed you want.

In your case, you only want to move left and right and let gravity pull your body down.  All of this should work well in the context of the physics.  You can control how fast your agent speeds up/slows down by controlling the linear acceleration.

This code base is available [here](http://nonlinearideas.com/making-missiles-hit-targets/).  There is also a video on YouTube ([here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=13r_iJmYLlA)) showing it in action for a missile. This is part of a larger framework but it is designed to be modular so take what you like and use it as you wish.

Was this helpful?

Comment: Thanks for replying in deail, But it didnt work for me if you play the game than u no it also go against the gravity. Like always jump in vertical direction if hit some object dont bounce back always jump in horizontal direction secondly i am getting problem because ball jump on diffferent heigh when i start moving it and at some point its velocity goes zero and its stop jumping?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the same effect by first making the ball continuously jump up and down to and from it's starting position. Then, you can change the ball's starting position using setTransform to move it whichever direction you want. For example:

```
void moveRight(b2Body* ball) { 
    ball->setTransform(b2Vec2(ball->getPosition().x + 100, 0), 0.0f);
}

void moveLeft(b2Body* ball) { 
    ball->setTransform(b2Vec2(ball->getPosition().x - 100, 0), 0.0f);
}
```